# Temperature Probability Distribution using datetime

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification, softmax

I am trying to build a model which predicts the temperature probability distribution at a given day and time.
For eg: The temperature can take upto 46 values (each rounded off to nearest whole number and treated as a different class). So as a part of this classification problem, I would like to predict what would be the probabiltity of each temperature class at a given time (a softmax distribution across the classes).

For training the model, I have taken a time series temperature data for 3 years and used it to find the cyclic features of hour_of_day, dayofweek and month.

Dataset looks like this :

| month_cos | month_sin | hour_sin | hour_sin | dayofweek_cos | dayofweek_sin | temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -2.449294e-16 | 1.0 | -0.965926 | 0.258819 | 0.0 | 1.0 | -10 |
| -2.449294e-16 | 1.0 | -0.866025 | 0.500000 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 8 |
| -2.449294e-16 | 1.0 | -0.707107 | 0.707107 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 34 |

Code for split into train test :

```
X = allcols.drop(columns=['round_temp'])
y = allcols[['round_temp']]
classes = y['round_temp'].nunique()
y['classes'] = y['round_temp'].astype("category").cat.codes
y = y.drop(columns=['round_temp'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

I have created a simple Neural Network as shown below:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(512,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
#model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(layers.Dense(64,activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(layers.Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I am getting a train and test set accuracy of around 7%. I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any hints on approaching this problem would be appreciated !