# Modifying the Accuracy metric in Keras for accounting for a deviation of +-2 from the prediction

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, metrics

I am trying to build a model which predicts the temperature probability distribution at a given day and time. For eg: The temperature can take upto 46 values (each rounded off to nearest whole number and treated as a different class).

For training the model, I have taken a time series temperature data for 3 years and used it to find the cyclic features of hour_of_day, dayofweek and month.

Exact link describing the dataset and network is given in this question : [Temperature Probability Distribution using datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72840302/19409126)

Now, I would like to modify the accuracy metric to account for a deviation of +-2 from the true value. For eg: if y_true = 5 and y_pred=7, since there is a difference of 2 between them, I want to consider this as a match.

I have tried modifying the metric in the following manner:

```
def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
  y_true_class = K.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
  y_pred_class = K.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
  if K.any(K.abs(y_true_class-y_pred_class) <= 2) :
    matches = K.cast(K.equal(y_true_class, y_pred_class), 'int32')
    accuracy = K.mean(matches)

  return accuracy
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Epoch 1/200
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-eda4366aff37> in <module>()
      3 early_stopping_monitor = EarlyStopping(patience=3)
      4 
----> 5 history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test, y_test),epochs=200,batch_size=16, callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "<ipython-input-23-64496d6a5cef>", line 5, in acc  *
        if K.any(K.abs(y_true_class-y_pred_class) <= 2) :

    ValueError: 'accuracy' must also be initialized in the else branch
```

I dont really have a 'else' condition. All I want is that the accuracy should be considered not only when it is equal but also if there is a minor difference of +-2. I think Ive done a mistake in the metric function. Could someone guide me towards the right path?

Comment: What is "K" in your code ?

Comment: K is the keras backend. I have imported it via - import keras.backend as K

Answer (score 0):

As per error log, error is in this statement **if (K.abs(y_true_class-y_pred_class) <= 2)**. Since the result of **K.abs(y_true_class-y_pred_class)** is an array, the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. You need to use **K.all** or **K.any** (like np.all or np.any) for a valid comparison. Like below:

```
if K.any(K.abs(y_true_class-y_pred_class) <= 2) :
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek, thanks for tip! The error has resolved now. But another error has cropped up ( ValueError: 'accuracy' must also be initialized in the else branch). I dont have an else condition as such. Is there a better way to frame this accuracy function such that the accuracy accounts for a minor +-2 difference?